# Touch sensor does not rotate after flipping the screen orientation

Tags: 22.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, touchscreen, chromebook

This question is for computers without a rotation sensor. For computers with a rotation sensor, autorotate can work in GNOME and KDE. [See this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469242/convertible-laptop-screen-does-not-autorotate-in-kubuntu/1469243#1469243).

---

I have a touch screen Chromebook (natively) running Ubuntu MATE 22.04.

The screen can be partially flipped, and I want to use the Chromebook as a tablet. There is no automatic rotation.

I can rotate the display in `Displays -> Rotation -> Upside Down`. However, that does not rotate the touch events.

For example, if I touch the top part of the screen (which now hosts of the bottom of the desktop because the display is flipped upside down in the settings), it opens menu in the top part of the desktop.

How to flip the touch events as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [autorotate](https://github.com/undg/autorotate) tool can do this.

First, [download the tool from github](https://github.com/undg/autorotate/releases/tag/v0.0.4-2), and unzip the binary named `autorotate` in `$HOME/.local/bin`. (In case you did not have the hidden folder `.local/bin`, create it, logout, and login).

Run `chmod +x $HOME/.local/bin/autorotate` to mark it as executable.

Next, detect your screen type using autorotate.

```
autorotate list
```

For me, the screen type is `eDP-1`.

Check that the command `autorotate invert --display eDP-1` inverts the display, and the command `autorotate normal --display eDP-1` restores the display orientation.

Finally, open `Keyboard shortcuts`, and assign custom keyboard shortcuts with these commands, so that you can quickly rotate the display (I am using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>),