# Convertible laptop screen does not autorotate in Kubuntu

Tags: screen, plasma, sensors, display-rotation

I have a HP x360 14a Chromebook (BLOOGUARD), and it supports automatic screen rotation in tablet mode in ChromeOS.

I [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466) Kubuntu 23.04 using [MrChromebox.tech UEFI](https://mrchromebox.tech/). How to enable automatic screen rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `iio-sensors-proxy` package, in case it is already not installed.

```
sudo apt install iio-sensors-proxy
```

### Wayland

Afterwards, log into a Plasma **Wayland** session, and enable tablet mode in system settings.

Reboot. Afterwards, screen should rotate automatically in the tablet mode.

### Xorg

The automatic screen rotation does not work out of the box in xorg. Install the [Screen Rotator](https://github.com/GuLinux/ScreenRotator) app.

First, install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt install -y git cmake build-essential qtbase5-dev libxrandr-dev libxi-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5sensors5-dev
```

Then, build it.

```
git clone https://github.com/GuLinux/ScreenRotator
mkdir ScreenRotator/build
cd ScreenRotator/build
cmake ..
make all
sudo make install
```

Finally, add the `Screen Rotator` app to the list of startup programs.