auto orient display when a display is rotated
my current display set up is two 1080p landscape monitors side to side with the laptop(primary) on the left side, i use the laptop as a tablet time to time, is there any way i can configure the displays like this automatically?
|      |_____________
|      |            |
|      |            |
|      |____________|   
|______|

because right now when the laptop is flipped the system does something like this:
|      |    _____________
|      |   |            |
|      |   |            |
|      |   |____________|   
|______|

its annoying having to change it manually every time

because right now when the laptop is flipped the system does something like this: - It is unclear what your system does. Is it that both laptop screen and the external screen flip, but you only want the laptop screen to flip?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using XOrg or Wayland (tell us the output of the command echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE$.

im using X11 on 22.04.5 the problem is the blank space the system creates when the laptop is flipped, i want the displays to be joined to each other

See this for xorg https://askubuntu.com/a/1469243/124466. On wayland it should be automatic

the problem is not rotation, the display auto rotates just fine, the problem is how the displays are sitting next to each other when the display is rotated
