# 360' monitor touch screen is off when rotated, draws in the opposite side , what to do?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, asus, monitor, touchscreen

I have an Asus Rog Flow 13 and its a touchscreen laptop that you can rotate it 360 to draw with stylus, but when i have my laptop open in the tablet mode , it draws on the opposite side of where i'm drawing and when i turn it back to laptop mode its all fine :| please help !!!!! i'm a designer and the stylus is my major use. I'm not so familiar with linux and its only been couple of months that i'm using it so is there anything i can do to fix this issue ?

thanks in advanced !  :)

Comment: Does the touchscreen also behave in the similiar manner as the stylus? That is, when you rotate the laptop, do the touch events map at proper places, i.e., when you touch the upper part of the screen, does it register a touch event at the bottom part of the screen?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: im using the latest version of ubuntu 23.04, so yeah when i touch the top it touches the bottom or when i touch left it touches the right , playing games with me :D

Comment: This software may work for you https://askubuntu.com/a/1456098/124466 (you may have to disable automatic rotation/tablet mode). Let us know if this tool works. If it does, we will create some desktop shortcuts so that you can easily rotate the screen afterwards.  (the keyboard shortcut part of that answer was for Ubuntu MATE, and may not work in regular Ubuntu, however, if the tool works otherwise, we can help you create desktop shortcuts for screen rotation)